# Rename or Remove Characters From a Filename with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, rename-item-cmdlet

I am trying to rename or remove part of a filename. I have a scheduled job that moves an updated file from one server to another. Once the file is moved it need to be renamed. For example: `Filename_01-23-AB.exe` to `Filename.exe` I want to remove everything from the "_" to the "." and leave the extension intact. I found the following code that should do this but I can't seem to get it to work. Am I headed down the right path here?

```
## Removes the build number from the filename of "Filename_XX-XX-XX.exe" leaving the new filename to be "Filename.exe" ##

$File = -Path "C:\Temp\TestPath\"

foreach ($File in gci *.exe) {
    $Fname = ($File.name).split('.')[0]  ## item before the '.' ##
    $Prefix = $Fname.split('_')[0] ## item before the '_' ##
    $Newname = $Prefix + '.exe'
    Rename-Item $file $Newname 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried simplifying what you're tying to do:

```
pushd "C:\Temp\TestPath\"
dir | ? { $_.Name -like "*.exe" } | 
% { Rename-Item $_ "$($_.BaseName.split('_')[0])$($_.Extension)" }
popd
```

First, this changes the directory your PowerShell is looking at to your defined directory (`pushd`).
Then it will get the contents of your directory, find all objects with the extension of .exe, and split the file's base name at the underscore. `popd` will then set the directory back to where-ever it was previous to running this script.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be simplifyed even more using a `regex` to remove everything between the first underscore and the file extension:

```
$Path= 'C:\Temp\TestPath\'
Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*_*.exe" | foreach {
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ($_.Name -replace '(?=_).+(?=\.)')
}
```

This also works when the filename doesn't contain an underscore.

And here the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sW8mU8/1).

Comment: `"hello world".Split("_")[0] -eq 'hello world'` :-)

Comment: Rename-Item : Source and destination path must be different.
At line:3 char:21
+     $_ | Rename-Item <<<<  -NewName ($_.Name -replace '(?=_).+(?=\.)')
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Temp\TestPath\.#ext:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

Comment: That's because you're finding files that doesn't contain an underscore. Filter out those first, ex. `Get-childItem -Path $path -Filter "*_*.exe"  | Foreach { ....`

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that this solution will rename any files found, not just .exes.

Comment: You are right @FrodeF. I will also edit my answer and use your filter, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## !not tested

try this

```
$path = 'C:\Temp\TestPath\'

gci $path *.exe | ? basename -match '_' | % {
    # if the file.txt already exists, rename it to file-1.txt and so on
    $num = 1
    $base = $_.basename.substring(0, $_.basename.indexof('_'))
    $ext = $_.extension
    $dir = $_.directory
    $newname = Join-Path $dir "$base$ext"
    while (Test-Path $newname) {
        $newname = Join-Path $dir "$base-$num$ext"
        $num++
    }

    # finally, rename the file
    ren $_.fullname $newname
}
```

Comment: Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length"
At line:6 char:34
+     $base = $_.basename.substring <<<< (0, $_.basename.indexof('_'))
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Comment: updated. i believe that error may have been caused by attempting to rename a file that does not have an `_` in the name