# batch file remove prefix of directory name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to remove a prefix of some directories.

I have many directories with names like '991234', '991235', '991236'. I want to remove the '99' from these folder names. The result needs to be a rename of the directories. They should be renamed to '1234', '1235', '1236'.

After some search I could write this script:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir 99* /A:D /b') do ren "%%a" "00_%%a"
```

this script find all directories starting with '99' and call ren for each of them. The problem is that I could not remove the '99' part to apply in the folder name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename or Remove Characters From a Filename with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350752/rename-or-remove-characters-from-a-filename-with-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
:: I use a test directory name that includes spaces to verify that the routine works with such directorynames
:: Use SET "sourcedir=." for the current directory
SET "sourcedir=u:\your files\t w o"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /A:D /b "%sourcedir%\99*"') do SET "dirname=%%a"&ECHO ren "%sourcedir%\%%a" "!dirname:~2!"

GOTO :EOF
```

The metavariable `%%a` needs to be assigned to a user variable for manipulation. Since the user variable will change value within the code block, `delayedexpansion` needs to be invoked.

See `for /?` and `set /?` for documentation, as well as Stephan's DELAYEDEXPANSION link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO REN` to `REN` to actually rename the directories.

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.